# LocationRequest and LocationServices.API are not resolved

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a high priority project under development.
I am trying to insert geo location into db so I found a service online and unfortunately `LocationRequest` and `LocationServices.API` are not resolved.
I am using the dependency `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'`

[image]

I tried adding the imports

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

You can find the code I used at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023986/android-gps-location-tracking-even-when-app-is-closednot-running-in-backgroun)

Comment: You compiled `maps` but `location` is a separate dependency

Answer (score 19):

Seems like you need to compile the `play-services-location` package.

Put these into the `build.gradle`

```
ext {
    playServicesVersion = '10.2.0' // update accordingly 
}

dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersion}"
}
```

Comment: @IbrahimBaz how did you know he was super in maps?

Answer (score 2):

Try this 
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'`
 in your app.gradle, and update the version regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'` 
worked for me