# Prevent closing app that has GPS tracking

Tags: android, memory, gps

I made an Android app that makes lots of stuff.
One of them is GPS tracking, saving marks to draw a trail.
Sometimes, Android closes my app when the phone is out of my sight in my pocket (I guess it's Android's "smart" memory management...??), and thus its GPS tracking stops.

I have used some tracking apps that keep running for long periods, so I guess they do something that I don't know.

How can I prevent this sudden stop? Can I add some kind of priority to the GPS tracking to prevent this, or some other way?

EDIT

Observe that I don't want just to get tracking even if app is closed. I want to prevent Android from closing the app, since the GPS tracking needs to be logged by the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GPS Location tracking even when app is closed(Not running in Background)/ScreenLocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023986/gps-location-tracking-even-when-app-is-closednot-running-in-background-screenl)

Comment: Not really. I don't want to get tracking even if app is closed. I want to prevent Android from closing the app, since the GPS tracking needs to be logged by the app.

Comment: How about service with `START_STICKY` option ?

Comment: This post https://stackoverflow.com/q/42126979/5909412

Comment: Maybe your `START_STICKY` suggestion works... (maybe I can even add a `wakeLock`?) I guess I only need to add this code to the service class (not sure how to check if this is working):

`@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_STICKY;
    }`

Comment: I'm not sure if I can  add a `wakeLock` to a service...?

Comment: You have to serach a bit https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock :)

Comment: Ok, I went for `wakeLock` + `START_STICKY`. I will report later how this worked. Thanks!!

Comment: If it works, we can post it as a valid answer

Comment: Maybe you can add it now, since it will take a while until I can fully check this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is to receive location updates even if after closing app, [This](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/background-location-updates-android-o/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) tutorial will help.

Comment: Not really. I need the GPS data to be logged by the app, so I don't want the app to be closed. And my app needs to work for Android >= 2.3.6, not just "O".

Comment: @LuisA.Florit this code works for each android version, and also works when app is open and closed, you can turn it off also when closing app, it has every scenario that you want.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit if you want your app not to be closed at all, then this is not development option, this is OS option that is not allowed for you.

Answer (score 0):

Create `ForegroundService`. System will not drop it until you close it by yourself.
More about in [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)

Comment: My GPS service is actually a bound service, since I want the app to be able to start/stop the service, and that the user is aware that the app has started the service and can stop it.